# preg_replace img tag in sequence in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I have a content, which is like

```
Test test test <img src="abc.png" alt='1'> test test <img src="123.png" alt='2'> test test
```

I would like to change it to be

`Test test test <id>1</id> test test <id>2</id> test test`

I have tried:

```
preg_match_all('/<img(.*?)alt=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)>/si', $content, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($result as $val) {                
          $content = preg_replace('/<img(.*?)alt=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)>/si', '<id>'.$val[2].'</id>', $content);
```

But it gives me:

```
Test test test <id>2</id> test test <id>2</id> test test
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: loop through `$result`, making use of the 4th argument of `preg_replace` to limit to 1 replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replacement inside the foreach contains problem. This is the fixed version.

```
<?php

$str = <<<term
Test test test <img src="abc.png" alt='1'> test test <img src="123.png" alt='2'> test test'
term;

preg_match_all('/<img.*?alt=[\'"](\d+)[\'"]>/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach($matches as $val) {                
    $str = preg_replace('/<img.*?alt=[\'"](' . $val[1] . ')[\'"]>/', '<id>'.$val[1].'</id>', $str);
}

var_dump($str);
```

Check it out here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad70f171ec5387451a29166865474de0f223f7c1

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like preg_match* is the right function to use here, evidenced by the need to loop.  It can be accomplished with just a preg_replace():

`preg_replace("/<.*? alt=[\"']([0-9]+)[\"'] *>/", '<id>${1}</id>', $teststr);`

This will operate on each matched expression independently, and do them all in one shot.  If you decide you do need the `src` value, you can adjust the expression as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
    $data = `Test test test <img src="abc.png" alt='1'> test test <img src="123.png" alt='2'> test test`;

    $replace = ["<img src='abc.png' alt='1'>","<img src='123.png' alt='2'>"];
    $value = ["<id>1</id>","<id>2</id>"];

    $dataNeeded = str_replace($replace, $value, $emailContent);

echo $dataNeeded;
```

Comment: Using 2 array to replace the value of multiple data.

Comment: $replace string wont be same. It is depending on user's input.